# want to install PyQt5 for slitaz

Tags: linux, python

I want to run an application that need python3 and pyqt5 in Slitaz 5. I am not pro in linux but managed to compile and install python3. now when I try to run application it tell me that need pyqt5. so I:

```
sudo pip3 install PyQy5
```

but I get

```
Could not find a version that satisifies the requirement PyQt5 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQt5
```

how can I fix it? should I compile qt5 from source code? then how?

Comment: Which version of Python 3 did you install? Is it at least 3.5?

Comment: @NasirRiley python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5

The above website provides the source code for compilation and installation.

On the website, it says "Before you can build PyQt5 you must have already built and installed SIP"

You might want to try first

```
pip3 install PyQt5-sip
```

then try

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

If this fails, building from the source code is the best bet, I guess.